# Ajax request to changing boolean value of object in django

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

i'm struggling to make ajax function that change the boolean value of an object without refreshing the page.
It returns error 500.

Model:
class Donation(models.Model):
is_taken = models.BooleanField(default=False)

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 50%; float:left" class="steps--container">
          {% for d in taken %}
            <div style="width: 80%; float: left">
              <h4>{{d.quantity}} bags of {% for c in d.categories.all %} {{c}} {% endfor %} by {{d.user.first_name}} {{d.user.last_name}} </h4>
              <input type="text" id="donation_id" value={{d.id}} hidden>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 20%; float:right">
              <input type="button" onclick="updateStatus()" value="{{d.id}}" Mark as not taken>
            </div>
            <br>
            {% endfor %}
</div>
```

JS:

```
function updateStatus() {
    var dId = document.getElementById("donation_id").value;
    var dIdInt = parseInt(dId, 10)
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/ajax/taken_or_not_taken/",
        data: {
            "donation_id": dIdInt
        }
    }).done(function(e){
        console.log("done")
        console.log(dIdInt)
    })
    .fail(function(e){
        console.log('error')
        console.log(e)
    })

}
```

View:

```
def taken_or_not_taken(request):
    obj = request.GET.get('donation_id', '')
    print(obj)
    return JsonResponse(obj)
```

Url:

```
url(r'^ajax/taken_or_not_taken/$', views.taken_or_not_taken, name='taken_or_not_taken'),
```

How can i make it works?

Comment: Your view does nothing

Comment: can you add the error stacktrace

Comment: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/taken_or_not_taken/?donation_id=2
[HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 139ms]

Comment: change  the last views line to :   return JsonResponse({'id':obj}). obj isn't a dict so Jsonresponse didnt work

Answer (score 0):

```
The full stacktrace says :
 line 121, in taken_or_not_taken return JsonResponse(obj)

line 555, in __init__'In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the the safe parameter to False.'
```

**JsonResponse**() should have a **dict** in argument and you pass an integer.

You can use the donation_id name:

```
def taken_or_not_taken(request):
    obj = request.GET.get('donation_id', '')
    print(obj)
    return JsonResponse({'donation_id':obj})
```

Or use the  safe=False parameter : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.JsonResponse

Answer (score 0):

Yea, i found it out, thanks guys anyway,
But the new problem appeared.
User still needs refresh the page to see the changes.
How to do it without refreshing page? Can i do it in django view?
Like:

```
def taken_or_not_taken(request):
    obj = request.GET.get('donation_id')
    data = {
        "id": obj
    }
    donate = Donation.objects.get(id=obj)
    if donate.is_taken == True: 
        donate.is_taken = False
        donate.save()
    elif donate.is_taken == False:
        donate.is_taken = True
        donate.save()
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: I've changed the ajax request type to a 'POST', added CSRF_TOKEN but then, the obj in my view == None.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax "POST" method to send the query to the server without refreshing the page.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url_of_query",
        data: {
            // Data you want to update
        }

        success: function(){
            console.log("Success msg");
            },
        error: function(){
            console.log("error");
        },
)}
```